# Cannot get Struts2.2.1 annotation to work on Netbeans 6.9

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans, struts2

I'm having a problem with Struts2.2.1 annotations annotation on NetBeans 6.9. This is my first time with the Struts2 framework. Am I doing something wrong??? I'm following a detailed tutorial and I'm getting the following errors on Apache Tomcat 6.0.29:

HelloAction.java

```
package br.ufg.inf.sas.action;

import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Action;
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Result;

public class HelloAction {

    @Action(value = "struts", results = {
        @Result(location = "/helloStruts.jsp", name = "hipage")})
    public String execute() {
        System.out.println("I'm getting the /struts page");
        System.out.println("Now I'll forward to helloStruts.jsp");
        return "hipage";
    }
}
```

helloStruts.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello Struts!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Apache Tomcat Error:

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Java\apache-tomcat-6.0.29"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\Java\apache-tomcat-6.0.29"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\Java\apache-tomcat-6.0.29\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_22"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\Java\apache-tomcat-6.0.29\bin\bootstrap.jar"
24/11/2010 18:36:03 org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\bin;.;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Java\apache-maven-3.0\bin;C:\Java\apache-ant-1.8.1\bin;C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\bin;C:\Web\apache-httpd-2.2\bin;C:\Web\mysql-5.1.53-winx64\bin;C:\Web\php-5.3.3-Win32-x86\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\TortoiseHg;C:\Program Files (x86)\CollabNet\Subversion Client;C:\MiKTeX-2.9\miktex\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared
24/11/2010 18:36:04 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
24/11/2010 18:36:04 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 997 ms
24/11/2010 18:36:04 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
24/11/2010 18:36:04 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.29
24/11/2010 18:36:04 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor host-manager.xml
24/11/2010 18:36:04 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor manager.xml
24/11/2010 18:36:05 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor StrutsSample.xml
24/11/2010 18:36:06 com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger info
INFO: Parsing configuration file [struts-default.xml]
24/11/2010 18:36:06 com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger info
INFO: Parsing configuration file [struts-plugin.xml]
24/11/2010 18:36:06 com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger info
INFO: Parsing configuration file [struts.xml]
24/11/2010 18:36:06 com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger error
GRAVE: Dispatcher initialization failed
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MethodInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:295)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ConstructorInjector.construct(ContainerImpl.java:431)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$5.create(ContainerBuilder.java:207)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.Scope$2$1.create(Scope.java:51)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$3.create(ContainerBuilder.java:93)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$7.call(ContainerBuilder.java:487)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$7.call(ContainerBuilder.java:484)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.callInContext(ContainerImpl.java:574)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder.create(ContainerBuilder.java:484)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.createBootstrapContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:252)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:193)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:66)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:371)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:415)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:69)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:51)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:295)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:422)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:115)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4001)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4651)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:546)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:637)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:563)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1277)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:321)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MethodInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:293)
        ... 42 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStackFactory.setContainer(OgnlValueStackFactory.java:85)
        ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Javassist library is missing in classpath! Please add missed dependency!
        at ognl.OgnlRuntime.<clinit>(OgnlRuntime.java:165)
        ... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javassist.ClassPool
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1645)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1491)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
        at ognl.OgnlRuntime.<clinit>(OgnlRuntime.java:162)
        ... 48 more
24/11/2010 18:36:06 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
GRAVE: Error filterStart
24/11/2010 18:36:06 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
GRAVE: Context [/StrutsSample] startup failed due to previous errors
24/11/2010 18:36:06 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThreadLocalMap
GRAVE: The web application [/StrutsSample] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [null] (value [com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10@16d2702]) and a value of type [java.lang.Object[]] (value [[Ljava.lang.Object;@11c2b67]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
24/11/2010 18:36:07 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory docs
24/11/2010 18:36:07 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory examples
24/11/2010 18:36:08 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory ROOT
24/11/2010 18:36:08 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
24/11/2010 18:36:08 org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
24/11/2010 18:36:08 org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/49  config=null
24/11/2010 18:36:08 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 4189 ms
24/11/2010 18:36:08 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext stop
INFO: Container org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/StrutsSample] has not been started
24/11/2010 18:36:09 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig checkResources
INFO: Undeploying context [/StrutsSample]
24/11/2010 18:36:09 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor StrutsSample.xml
24/11/2010 18:36:10 com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger info
INFO: Parsing configuration file [struts-default.xml]
24/11/2010 18:36:10 com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger info
INFO: Parsing configuration file [struts-plugin.xml]
24/11/2010 18:36:10 com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger info
INFO: Parsing configuration file [struts.xml]
24/11/2010 18:36:10 com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger error
GRAVE: Dispatcher initialization failed
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MethodInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:295)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ConstructorInjector.construct(ContainerImpl.java:431)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$5.create(ContainerBuilder.java:207)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.Scope$2$1.create(Scope.java:51)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$3.create(ContainerBuilder.java:93)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$7.call(ContainerBuilder.java:487)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$7.call(ContainerBuilder.java:484)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.callInContext(ContainerImpl.java:574)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder.create(ContainerBuilder.java:484)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.createBootstrapContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:252)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:193)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:66)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:371)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:415)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:69)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:51)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:295)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:422)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:115)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4001)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4651)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:546)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:637)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:521)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1359)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:297)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:836)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:761)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1500)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:849)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:351)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:199)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:563)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MethodInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:293)
        ... 54 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStackFactory.setContainer(OgnlValueStackFactory.java:85)
        ... 59 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Javassist library is missing in classpath! Please add missed dependency!
        at ognl.OgnlRuntime.<clinit>(OgnlRuntime.java:165)
        ... 60 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javassist.ClassPool
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1645)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1491)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
        at ognl.OgnlRuntime.<clinit>(OgnlRuntime.java:162)
        ... 60 more
24/11/2010 18:36:10 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
GRAVE: Error filterStart
24/11/2010 18:36:10 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
GRAVE: Context [/StrutsSample] startup failed due to previous errors
24/11/2010 18:36:10 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThreadLocalMap
GRAVE: The web application [/StrutsSample] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [null] (value [com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10@12922f6]) and a value of type [java.lang.Object[]] (value [[Ljava.lang.Object;@1b66b06]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally fixed it!

It seems that some bundles on struts2 now requires javassist (byteloader manipulation library from JBoss Project). Just downloaded javassist and added to the library folder.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that was the case but in latest release it has been removed